# Is it possible to write a file to a library via javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, sharepoint-2013

If I have the data of an imagefile as a base64 encoded variable in javascript. Is it possible to write that data as a file into a image library in sharepoint 2013?

Thus writing the data with for example web services being called by javascript/jquery?
(I'm currently preffering every method that does not require a second .aspx page or a second list where possible. Also I can't use Image columns with references as publish is not active, thus the idea grew if it is not possible just with javascript/jquery without having to rely on anything else but didn't find anything about that when I searched).

Comment: SP 2013 has a REST API so it might be doable

Comment: is there anywhere a documentation for the API? (a useable one....tried it with the webservices but didnt find anything good online)

Comment: I'd start from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: hmmmm if I get it correct I would need to create the file there with a PUT -File command and then checkin for teh file to be availbel?